# Retrieve matching user data

Tags: iphone, arrays, json, sqlite, authentication

I have login page with username and password. When i enter correct credentials it will goes to another view controller. In this view controller i have button to click matching user information. If username matches I need to retrieve only their datas and display.

code:

viewController.m :

```
if ([responseData length]){

    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[responseData JSONValue];                
    NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[responseData JSONValue];                
    NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [dict objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];
    NSInteger id1 = [(NSNumber *) [dict1 objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];               

   NSLog(@"%d",success);
    if(success == 1){
        NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
        [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:overlay animated:YES];

    } else {
        NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [dict objectForKey:@"error_message"];
        [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
    }
}
```

Above code `objForKey=@"success"` contains `username & password.` `ObjForKey=@"id"` contain every user id. If this id matches I need to display that id data.

```
viewController1.m:
```

Here i need to get `ObjForKey=@"id"`. company_id storing `ObjForKey=@"id"` data. How to pass `ObjForKey=@"id"` from `viewController` to `ViewController1.m` in select query. `CategoryNames` & `categoryIds` Array containing particular user product name & Ids. If `ObjForKey=@"id"` matches I need to get that user `categoryNames` & `categoryIds`

```
if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {

    const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_name FROM categories where company_id = ObjForKey=@"id";
    NSLog(@"sql is %s",sql);

    categoryNames = [NSMutableArray array];
    categoryIds = [NSMutableArray array];
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    // int catID = 0;
  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {

    // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
    while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
        NSString *categoryName = [[NSString alloc] 
                                  initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
        NSLog(@"catName is %@",categoryName);
        NSInteger categoryId = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);

        [categoryNames addObject:categoryName];
        [categoryIds addObject:@(categoryId)];
    } 
  }
}
```

Here UIActionSheet displays categoryNames for particular user id:

```
TSActionSheet *actionSheet = [[TSActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Design"];       


 for (int i = 0; i<[categoryNames count]; i++ ) {           

            NSLog(@"catearray is %@",categoryNames);

            [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:[categoryNames objectAtIndex:i] block:^{

                [self actionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:i];

        }];
```

Comment: This is for multiple user. Each user register their name in my server. After registeration one user id will generated in my server for each user. Then each user write something. This stores in each user. If user install the app & enter username,password it will goes to viewcontroller1.m . In viewcontroller1.m having button, If button click i need to retrieve particular user data from server.

Comment: @Meda: Did you undertand?

Comment: are you asking how to pass the id from one view to the other ?

Comment: You are correct. But how can i pass this Id to sql query? const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_name FROM categories where company_id = ObjForKey=@"id";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NSUserDefaults` for that:

```
if ([responseData length]){

    NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);
    NSMutableDictionary *dict=[responseData JSONValue];                                
    NSInteger success = [(NSNumber *) [dict objectForKey:@"success"] integerValue];

    NSLog(@"%d",success);
    if(success == 1){
        //save the ID
        NSInteger id1 = [(NSNumber *) [dict objectForKey:@"id"] integerValue];
        NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [userData setInteger:id1 forKey:@"id"];
        [userData synchronize];       
        NSLog(@"Login SUCCESS");
        [self alertStatus:@"Logged in Successfully." :@"Login Success!"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:overlay animated:YES];

    } else {
        NSString *error_msg = (NSString *) [dict objectForKey:@"error_message"];
        [self alertStatus:error_msg :@"Login Failed!"];
    }
}
```

And Then To get the `id` value back you would do this in ViewController1.m:

```
//Get the Id
NSUserDefaults *userData = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger id1 = [userData integerForKey:@"id"];
```

EDIT:

> But how can i pass this Id to sql query?

Not sure why you have `objForKey` in your query try this:

```
NSString *sql  = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                    @"SELECT id,cat_name FROM categories where company_id = %d", id1];
```

Comment: You are correct. But how can i pass this Id to sql query?   const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_name FROM categories where company_id = ObjForKey=@"id";

Comment: @user2674668 you see the second part of my answer I showed how to get the Id back, which part you need help

Comment: It's correct. But how to pass to this line: SELECT id,cat_name FROM categories where company_id = ObjForKey=@"id"

Comment: @user2674668 I added more details, let me know if it worked, we will get this sorted out

Comment: I didn't use NSString. Shall i use below:  const char *sql = "SELECT id,cat_name FROM categories where company_id = %d", id1;

Comment: no replace it with `NSString` if there is an error let me know